# Smarty template system show data if exists?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm using a script that uses the Smarty template system.  With this code I'm able to show a custom field from client profiles:

```
{$clientsdetails.customfields1}
```

But if the field is blank, it doesn't show anything.  What would I need to change to make it show something like "This feature isn't available for you."

I know it's probably a simple fix, I'm just not familiar with the Smarty template system...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
{$clientsdetails.customfields1|default:"something"}
```